How to debug production containers using kubectl debug under root user?
I’m facing an issue related to our strict security policies, which are configured according to best practices. Below is the security context we are using:
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: <user id, any except 0>
    privileged: false
  containers:
    securityContext:
      runAsNonRoot: true
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false

This setup works well to harden our production containers, but we’re running into a problem when it comes to debugging.
For example, when we need to verify network connectivity using TCPDUMP, we can use kubectl debug --profile=netadmin. Full command:  kubectl debug -it <target-container>  --image=nicolaka/netshoot --profile=netadmin --target=<target-container> -- tcpdump
This allows us to get the necessary NET_ADMIN, but the debugging container runs under a non-root user, resulting in the following error:
Warning: would violate PodSecurity "baseline:latest": non-default capabilities (containers "debugger-jb8sv", "debugger-zklnx", "debugger-mmt72", "debugger-gd8lt" must not include "NET_ADMIN", "NET_RAW" in securityContext.capabilities.add)
tcpdump: eth0: You don't have permission to perform this capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)

I guess it should be fixed with sysadmin profile but as of now, the sysadmin profile is not available in kubectl 1.29.
Can anyone suggest a way to tackle this issue while maintaining our security standards? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

@  SystemFailure Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?

Silly question - do you have elevated host access ? You could just set up wire capture on the pod's NIC. Other tools and use cases, agreed with consensus - wait for official release.

If "sysadmin" or similar profiles are planned for future Kubernetes versions, wait for their official release. Using experimental features is not recommended in production, SO keep updated. So you apply Pod Security Standards to the latest version: baseline standard in enforce mode.

This
tutorial
shows you how to enforce the baseline Pod Security Standard at the
cluster level which applies a standard configuration to all namespaces
in a cluster.To apply Pod Security Standards to
specific namespaces, refer to official kuberntes document on Apply
Pod Security Standards at the namespace level.
The baseline Pod Security Standard provides a convenient middle ground
that allows keeping the exemption list short and prevents known
privilege escalations. Additionally, to prevent pods from failing in
the kube-system, you'll exempt the namespace from having Pod Security
Standards applied.
As per the Kubernetes document on Pod security standards : Other
alternatives for enforcing policies are being developed in the
Kubernetes ecosystem, such as: Kubewarden, Kyverno,OPA Gatekeeper

.
You can consider less privileged tools: Look for debugging tools that don't require "NET_ADMIN" for their core functionality. For example: nslookup, dig, ping and traceroute, curl etc.. also kubectl exec to run commands within the target container and inspect its logs. kubectl logs to view container logs.
Refer to this official doc  Configure a Security Context for a Pod or Container for more information.

Running your traffic through a MITM proxy also comes to mind. I like Burp, but in a container (in text mode) you might get more mileage from mitmproxy.
